# Yaml instance not created when constructor argument is passed

Tags: java, yaml

I am using snakeyml to read yml file and load it in Java objects.

Issue:
When I do a `Yaml yml = new Yaml()`, yml instance is created. But when I pass the constructor argument, the yml instance is not created. I don't see an exception either. This is the complete code.

```
private static YamlConfig readStatsConfig()
        throws IOException {

    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(configFile));
    Constructor constructor = new Constructor(YamlConfig.class);

    TypeDescription description = new TypeDescription(YamlConfig.class);
    description.putListPropertyType("resources", YamlConfig.Resource.class);
    constructor.addTypeDescription(description);

    TypeDescription description = new TypeDescription(
                    YamlConfig.Resource.class);
    description.putListPropertyType("stats", YamlConfig.StatsInfo.class);
    constructor.addTypeDescription(description);

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);

    YamlConfig cfg = (YamlConfig) yaml.load(input);

    mainLogger.info(cfg);

    return cfg;
}
```

Code exit in the following statement:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"instance is not created"*? `new Yaml(constructor)` will either return an instance, or it will throw an exception. There are really no other possible outcomes *(unless the JVM itself crashes)*.

Comment: I meant code exit in the statement , Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor). I debugged the code to see whether the statement Yaml yaml1=new Yaml() works, and it worked. I think there is some issue in the constructor instance created, but I don't see any issue in that either based on my debug. Is there any other suggestions to implement the same functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by *"code exit in the statement"*? Your method stops running there because of an exception? If so, what does the exception say?

Comment: I see the JVM exit code 0, so the JVM is not crashing. I enclosed the Yaml yml = new Yaml(constructor) in a try/catch block and it does not throw any exception either. I ran the code in debug mode and the program terminated exactly at the statement Yaml yml = new Yaml(constructor) with exit code 0 and with no exception.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with TestNG. This sounds wierd, but here is the solution that worked.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakeyaml-core/rJdKP6o9sYM

Answer (score 0):

```
I fixed the issue by excluding snakeyml dependency in TestNG JARs. All we need to do is to add the following in the project POM has dependency with TestNG.

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1</version>
             <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```